# Solr MultiValued fields returned in a CSV

Tags: csv, solr, hive

I'm trying to write a Solr query that does something similar to a LATERAL EXPLODE with Hive and returns the results in a CSV. I want to return one "row" for each value in a multiValued field and replicate the "parent" value.

This is my query...

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=*%3A*&fl=parent,id&wt=csv
```

Which returns this output.

```
parent,id
10,"4100,4435"
11,"376,190,4542"
12,"141,142"
```

However, I'd like the results of the query to return something like this:

```
parent,id
10,4100
10,4435
11,376
11,190
11,4542
12,141
12,142
```

Is this possible with Solr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denormalise your data and use the [Result Grouping](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Result+Grouping) of Solr.

**Store data like this:**

```
parent,id,id_group
10,"4100","4100,4435"
10,"4435","4100,4435"
11,"376","376,190,4542"
11,"190","376,190,4542"
11,"4542","376,190,4542"
12,"141","141,142"
12,"142","141,142"
```

---

Now when you want single row for each of multivalue field.

**Query:**
     http://localhost:8983/solr/awesome-collection/select?q=*:*&fl=parent,id&wt=json&indent=true

**Result:**

```
parent,id
10,4100
10,4435
11,376
11,190
11,4542
12,141
12,142
```

---

When you want to group the data as

**Query:**
    http://localhost:8983/solr/awesome-collection/select?q=*:*&fl=parent,id_group&wt=json&indent=true&group=true&group.field=parent&group.format=simple

**Result:**

```
parent,id_group
10,"4100,4435"
11,"376,190,4542"
12,"141,142"
```